# how can i make flowpane scroll when resized

Tags: scroll, javafx-8, scenebuilder, flowpane

I want to show a scrollbar automatically when the window is resized to be able to see all the rectangles

Before resizing:
[image: befor resizing]

After resizing:
[image: after resizing]

In the bottom, the rectangles disappear but they are still there.
so is there a way to combine the Flowpane with a Scrollpane ?

I'm using SceneBuilder and this is the fxml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<FlowPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
   </children>
</FlowPane>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is: Simply use the `FlowPane` as content for the `ScrollPane` and use `fitToWidth` to make make the `ScrollPane` set the width of the content according to the available width...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<!-- make ScrollPane resize the content width -->
<ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <content>
      <!-- do not put bounds on the FlowPane size -->
      <FlowPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
         </children>
      </FlowPane>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```